# Import modules to environment by calling another script

Tags: python, python-module

I am trying to import modules to my current environment that are listed in a secondary script. Below is a model of the problem in addition to my attempted solution.

Module script:

```
# Import modules (just one for the example)
import pandas as pd
# Set a variable that can be checked
modules_imported =  True
# Confirmation message
print("Setup script finsihed!")
```

Main Script:

```
# Import minimum required modules
import importlib
 
# Run module script
if 'modules_imported' not in globals():

    start_up_script = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(
        name="mod_name",
        location="/home/solebay/project/module_script.py"
        )
    my_mod = importlib.util.module_from_spec(start_up_script)
    start_up_script.loader.exec_module(my_mod)
```

This attempt however fails, as demonstrated by the following checks:

```
# Litmus Test 1
if 'modules_imported' in globals():
    setup_status = 'successfully run!'
else:
    setup_status = 'failed!'    
print('Modules script: ' + setup_status)

# Litmus test 2
try:
    pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None, "display.max_columns", None)
except:
    pandas_commands = "failing!"
else:
    pandas_commands = "functioning!"   
print("Pandas commands: " + pandas_commands)
```

How do I load modules into my current environment by calling on a startup script containing a module list?

Answer (score 3):

The reason your attempt doesn't work is that `globals()` aren't actually globals; they are local to the current module.

But if I understand your purpose correctly, you're making it more complicated than it needs to be. Simply use `import *` in your main script. You can use [`__all__`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package) to indicate what variables should be imported, in case you have private variables in `module_script.py` that should not be imported into other modules.

`module_script.py`

```py
import pandas as pd

__all__ = ["pd"]

print("Setup script finsihed!")
```

`main_script.py`

```py
from module_script import *

pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None, "display.max_columns", None)
```

Note that Python will only run the code in a module once, even if that module is imported multiple times from different places.

Comment: I had very much over complicated the problem. Is there a simple way to do this if `module_script` is in a sub folder, e.g. `from setup/module_script import *`. I tried using a path but it wasn't happy about having a setup dir.

Comment: Yes, that's possible. I recommend you read up on the basics of Python modules.